# Как раскодировать процентное кодирование url Python?

Tags: python, html, кодировка, utf-8

Хочу достать данные из url, но ресурс отдает мне закодированный url.
Как с помощью Python раскодировать его, как указано в примере на картинке?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16566128/8324991

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это называется `URL-encoded` формат:

```
import urllib.parse

test = 'https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1507154/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-url-python'
print(urllib.parse.unquote(test))
```

Так же если варианты когда в строке всречаются `+` тогда используем другой метод:

```
test = 'example.com/code=HOW%20TO+Articles' 
print(urllib.parse.unquote_plus(test))
```

Так же полезно будет знать как создать закодированную строку самостоятельно:

```
u = 'что-то что нужно закодировать'
url = urllib.parse.quote(u.encode('utf8'))
print(url)
```